# RxJS BehaviorSubject cashing request from http call

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm having hard time finding neet solution for cashing http request to BehaviorSubject. I wanted to have only single method for cashing and getting value. Example below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataStoreService {

  private readonly initialState: DataState = {
    data: string,
    loaded: false
  };

  private data$: BehaviorSubject<DataState> = new BehaviorSubject<DataState>(this.initialState);

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  getData$(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.data$.asObservable()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((state: DataState) => {
          if (!state.loaded) {
            this.dataService.getData$(id);
          } else {
            return of(state.data);
          }
        }),
        withLatestFrom(this.data$.asObservable()),
        map(([data, state]) => {
          if (!state.loaded) {
            this.data$.next({
              loaded: true,
              data
            });
          }
          return data;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it yet (service not working), but looks ok for now. Anybody knows any better solution to have less piping and conditionals (if/else) in rxjs for this kind of usage?

Comment: If you are serious about caching you need to look at a store based solution such as ngrx - however, if you cant be bothered with the learning curve or dont have time then you could just bung data in localstorage and retrieve it from there - to be honest your current solution looks doable

Comment: Setting new ngrx state just to retrive one object (I have in app whole json obj instead string) is overkill I think. I'm trying to keep KISS principal wherever I can. Anyway instead calling backend service I would need to invoke action and handle it in effect. Else I would need to remember to call action that will cash data from backend service somewhere in service or component, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `BehaviorSubject` you could use the operator `shareReplay` which uses a `ReplaySubject` internally and replays the n most recent values to future subscribers.

```ts
private data$: Observable<string>;

getData$(id: string): Observable<string> {
  if (!this.data$) {
    this.data$ = this.dataService.getData$(id).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  } 
  return this.data$;
}
```

The first subscription to `getData$` will call `this.dataService.getData$`. All later subscriptions will get the data from that first call replayed by `data$`.

Comment: Neet solution. You know of any downsides when using it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at this a bit differently and not actually using the behavior subject, just a variable. If that is an option for you, you could consider:

```
data;

getData$(id: string): Observable<string> {
  if (data) {
    return of(data)
  } else {
    return this.dataService.getData$(id).pipe(
      tap(dat => this.data = dat)
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Any downsides in using this solution? Anything that I should be wary?

Comment: I don't think that there is really anything that you should wary about. Since we are returning data variable as an observable (if it has data), there isn't even the mutability issue. I loooove BehaviorSubject (lol) and use it a lot but in these cases I like to use this approach, much cleaner in my opinion. The consumer doesn't need to care where the data comes from (API or variable stored in service), it just subscribes to the function :)

Answer (score 1):

BehaviourSubjects do have a very simple value-accessor in ".value".

So your code could look something like

```
getData$(id: String): Observable<string> {
  const dataValue = this.data$.value;
  if (dataValue.loaded === true) {
    return of(dataValue.data);
  } else {
    return this.dataService.getData$(id).pipe( map( (result: string) => { this.data$.next({ loaded: true, data: result}; return of(result); );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's nice solution. Still it would be nice to have it pure reactive, so I could use it on other scenarios then BehaviourSubject.